# PATCH request with Retrofit, get back JSON

Tags: json, web-services, retrofit, patch, okhttp

This is my function which makes the PATCH request:

```
  public void patchWithParams2(Integer id, JSONObject params, final JsonCallback jsonCallback){
    String URL = Constants.API_ENDPOINT + "/trips";
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new OkClient()) //very important!!!
            .setEndpoint(URL)//base url
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {//You may not need to pass headers, but I do, so this is how it's done.
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
                    try{
                        String token = Utils.getEncodedAuthToken(PSLocationCenter.getInstance().pref);
                        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + token);
                        PackageInfo pInfo = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                        request.addHeader("User-agent", "Passenger/" + pInfo.versionCode + " (" + System.getProperty("http.agent") + ")");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("","error trying to add user agent");
                        Utils.appendLog("ERROR trying to set agent:" + e.getMessage(),true);
                    }
                    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                }
            })
            .build();
    PatientInfoAPI patchService = restAdapter.create(PatientInfoAPI.class);
    TripUpdate trip = new TripUpdate();
    trip.setNotes("#business");
    patchService.update(trip, String.valueOf(id), new retrofit.Callback<TripUpdate>() {
        @Override
        public void success(TripUpdate userUpdates, retrofit.client.Response response) {
            Log.i("All is good", "Nickname:" +  userUpdates.toString());
            Log.i("All is good", "Nickname:" +  response.getBody().toString());
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                String line;

                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("","error trying to get response" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("","error trying to get response2" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("All is good", "Nickname2:" +  result);
            jsonCallback.onResponse(null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.i("All is good", "Nickname:" +  error.getLocalizedMessage().toString());
            jsonCallback.onResponse(null, null);
        }
    });
}
```

I get back a valid response, but I cannot parse it to JSON.
In this while, I get back the following error:

```
   try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("","error trying to get response" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Error:

```
04-20 17:43:57.877: E/(23529): error trying to get responseclosed
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529): java.io.IOException: closed
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:367)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.services.PSTripService$17.success(PSTripService.java:1695)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.services.PSTripService$17.success(PSTripService.java:1683)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-20 17:43:57.877: W/System.err(23529):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-20 17:43:57.887: W/System.err(23529):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also this is the interface that creates the PATH and BODY:

```
 public interface PatientInfoAPI {
@PATCH("/{id}")
public void update(@Body TripUpdate updatedDAta, @Path("id") String  id, Callback<TripUpdate> response);
}
```

Is is posible to send the Body directly as a Json object, and not from the Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forced the interface to retrieve a JsonElement:

```
     @PATCH("/{id}")
public void update(@Body TripPatch updatedDAta, @Path("id") String  id, Callback<JsonElement> response);
```

And then I get it like this:

```
   String jsonObject = userUpdates.toString();
```